# Trying to use add = True and I get an error message

Tags: spatial

I am Trying to use add = True and I get an error message. How can I do it?

This is my code

```
quadratcount(schools.pp)

plot(schools.sp, col = "red")

plot(quadratcount(schools.pp), add= T)`
```

and this is the error message I get

```
Error in (function (x, y = NULL, density = NULL, angle = 45, border = NULL, : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a simple typo: In the first plot command you write `plot(schools.sp, col = "red")`, where you probably meant `plot(schools.pp, col = "red")`. For future questions please provide a reproducible example where we can run each line including `library(spatstat)` and the definition of `schools.pp` etc. If you can't share your data just either:

- use the first few points of your data
- use a built-in dataset
- generate artificial data